# SelectField return value wtf-forms

Tags: python, forms

I have created a SelectField in python with this code:

```
condition = SelectField(u'Condition', choices = [(1,condition_string[5]),(2, condition_string[4]),(3, condition_string[3]),(4, condition_string[2]),(5, condition_string[1])], validators =[validators.Required(message=u'Must enter the condition of the book')])
```

my question is: what will be returned from the html when the user submits their selection:
   will it return a value from condition_string[] or will it return the number it is ordered on the list,
for example: if use selects the first option, will it return '1' or the value from condition_string[5]?

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

From the [WTForms docs](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField):

> Select fields keep a *choices* property which is a sequence of *(value, label)* pairs. The value portion can be any type in theory, but as form data is sent by the browser as strings, you will need to provide a function which can coerce the string representation back to a comparable object.

The (ill-formed) question is,

> "what will be returned from the html?"

I'm assuming you mean to ask something like:

> **what will the value of `condition.data` be after processing data received from a browser?**

The answer is: a string. It could be literally *any* string -- that's why you have to validate.

But if the user is co-operating, the browser will send back the *value, as a string*, and `condition.data` will return `u'1'`, or `u'2'`, etc. Note the *value* is the first element of the *(value, label)* pair and is not necessarily its position in the `choices` list.

As is, the field will never validate, as the numbers provided as values (`int`s) will not match the string data (which is by default coerced to unicode). This is why the docs say, ["you will need to provide a function which can coerce the string representation back to a comparable object."](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)